# When the ending is abrupt and the protagonist dies should you explore the aftermath or can you just end it abruptly with a hint of what's to come?

Tags: creative-writing, ending, protagonist, death

I have a story where the protagonist dies as a martyr and fuels the fire of rebellion against an evil empire, but I am not sure how I should approach it and whether it's perfectly fine to end the story abruptly.

Exploring the aftermath of a main protagonist's death can provide closure for the readers or viewers, allowing them to understand the consequences of the protagonist's demise and see how it affects other characters or the world of the story. It can also add emotional weight and depth to the narrative, and offer a sense of resolution or catharsis. This is the usual way people end their story.

On the other hand, ending a story abruptly with a hint of what's to come can create a different effect. It can leave the readers or viewers with a sense of ambiguity, allowing them to interpret the ending and imagine the possible outcomes themselves. It can also leave room for speculation and discussion, fostering engagement and leaving a lasting impact on the audience.

Can we truly say that the first one is always preferable to the other, or have you seen plenty of people make the second option work?